# Erase network folder access history

Tags: networking

Hi I used to access some folders on one of our servers from my machine windows explorers by typing an address similar to the below in run.

\192.168.0.119\d$

first time it asked for my password. After that I think I asked it to save my password and it doesn't ask again. how do I delete the history, and make it ask for my password again?

Answer (score 0):

Open the credential manager by searching "Manage network passwords" in the Start menu, or by opening *Control Panel → User Accounts – Credential Manager*.

You can find stored fileserver passwords in the "Windows Credentials" section.

Note: You will get the password prompt *only* if the server doesn't accept your local Windows username/password. If both computers have identical accounts set up, you'll need to use *Map network drive* to force a different account to be used.